# Purchased a used MacBook4, 1 and want to downgrade OS

Tags: downgrade

I just purchased a used MacBook 4, 1.
Its running Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5

I was hoping to run older software from 2004 that ran on my eMac on OS X.

Can I downgrade the OS somehow?

I get the error message "You can't open the application Install Traktor FS 2 because PowerPC applications are no longer supported"

Help!

Comment: You'd have to downgrade to at least **Mac OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard** and install [**Rosetta**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)) to try an run a **PowerPC** application on an **Intel** based **Mac**.

Comment: See this for a plan: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/402726/237687

Comment: From what I can tell from a cursory Google Search, the Macbook 4,1 shipped with Leopard and you should be able to install Snow Leopard without problems—you don't need to go through the ridiculous hack process in the linked answer. Just get a retail Snow Leopard DVD off eBay (or Macintosh Garden) and install it.