# Can you downgrade a 2021 iMac to Mojave?

Tags: imac, mojave, downgrade

We work on an older SAN that will not run on OS beyond Mojave.  And yes, if money was no option and I could replace 400TB with a more modern system I absolutely would.  However, it is what it is and I would like to get the best system I can for our current environment.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Generally speaking earlier versions of macOS do not have the necessary support software (drivers, etc) for systems shipped with a later version of macOS. That said. It *sometimes* works. You would need to create a bootable Mojave installer and see if will boot and allow you to install. Chances are it will not. But some people here have had success with putting an older macOS version on newer hardware. Perhaps they will speak up.

Comment: What do you mean with „ SAN that will not run on OS beyond Mojave“? SANs don‘t run on macOS as such, what exactly doesn’t run?

Comment: If you want to try to force it to boot, this is how you would do it. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402726/how-can-i-attempt-to-boot-an-older-version-of-macos-than-my-hardware-supports/402727

Comment: It's a modified version of XSAN that connects over fiber.

Answer (score 3):

You can‘t run old macOS versions on newer hardware, there usually are some drivers missing. There are special constellations in some cases (and we probably have some answers beneath similar questions) but as of now it‘s highly unlikely that there is a way for a 2020/21 iMac to run Mojave.

Options which may work for you

- Run Mojave in a VM and access the SAN from there
- Get an older Mac mini/iMac capable of running Mojave via eBay or similar